# Make a query with only no null register

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I'm having trouble putting together a query and would like the community's help. I have the following scenario: 2 tables (SUPPLIER and SERVICE). Making the following select:

```
select f.supplier_id, s.planned_value, s.executed_value
from supplier f
inner join service s on f.id_supplier = s.id_supplier
```

I have the following result:

| SUPPLIER_ID | PLANNED_VALUE | EXECUTED_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 100 |
| 2 | 200 | 200 |
| 2 | 300 | null |

I need to set up a query where it returns the supplier records, without repetition, only when the performed value column of all services from that supplier are filled, that is, in the scenario above, the result should be:

| SUPPLIER_ID | SUPPLIER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |

And when the third line, which is null, is filled in, the response should be:

| SUPPLIER_ID | SUPPLIER_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC |
| 2 | DEF |

Thank you to anyone who can support

I tried to use count, without success

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  supplier (id_supplier, supplier_name) as
  3    (select 1, 'ABC' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'DEF' from dual
  5    ),
  6  service (id_supplier, planned_Value, executed_value) as
  7    (select 1, 100, 100  from dual union all
  8     select 2, 200, 200  from dual union all
  9     select 2, 300, null from dual
 10    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 11  select f.id_supplier, f.supplier_name
 12  from supplier f
 13  where not exists (select null
 14                    from service s
 15                    where s.id_supplier = f.id_supplier
 16                      and (   s.planned_value  is null
 17                           or s.executed_value is null
 18                          )
 19                   );

ID_SUPPLIER SUPPLIER_NAME
----------- ---------------
          1 ABC

SQL>
```

If all values are set:

```
SQL> with
  2  supplier (id_supplier, supplier_name) as
  3    (select 1, 'ABC' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'DEF' from dual
  5    ),
  6  service (id_supplier, planned_Value, executed_value) as
  7    (select 1, 100, 100  from dual union all
  8     select 2, 200, 200  from dual union all
  9     select 2, 300, 300  from dual            --> EXECUTED_VALUE is now 300 (was NULL)
 10    )
 11  select f.id_supplier, f.supplier_name
 12  from supplier f
 13  where not exists (select null
 14                    from service s
 15                    where s.id_supplier = f.id_supplier
 16                      and (   s.planned_value  is null
 17                           or s.executed_value is null
 18                          )
 19                   );

ID_SUPPLIER SUPPLIER_NAME
----------- ---------------
          1 ABC
          2 DEF

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an analytic query:

```sql
SELECT f.supplier_id,
       s.planned_value,
       s.executed_value
FROM   (
  SELECT f.supplier_id,
         s.planned_value,
         s.executed_value,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN s.executed_value IS NULL THEN 1 END)
           OVER (PARTITION BY f.supplier_id) AS has_null
  FROM   supplier f
         INNER JOIN service s
         ON f.supplier_id = s.id_supplier
)
WHERE  has_null = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to do a table join. I suggest selecting all records from supplier table and for each of them use exists() to check if there is a record with null EXECUTED_VALUE in service table.

```sql
select f.supplier_id, f.supplier_name
from supplier f
where not exists (
    select null 
      from service s 
      where f.id_supplier = s.id_supplier 
        and s.executed_value is null
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**